# How do Patterns and Cover Interact?

Tags: combat, attack, area-of-effect, cover, lancer-rpg

I am having trouble finding a confirmation one way or another in relation to how cover does or doesn't affect Pattern attacks, and if it does, when and how. I suspect that it's actually spelled out somewhere and I'm missing the quote.

Example of an interaction scenario that caused this uncertainty for me:

Let's say you have the Barbarossa Siege Cannon. You shoot it in siege mode. It is Arcing and Blast 2. You are in a broken landscape, where there's a bunch of buildings (cover), and a target or several behind them. So of course you shoot in an arc *over* the buildings, with the target(s) being within the blast area. Arcing by itself doesn't help ignore cover, but the blast is coming from a direction where cover doesn't stand in-between . . . but the shooter doesn't directly see the target(s). I'm not sure whether the Cover penalty applies or not.

For a less ambiguous scenario, imagine the same terrain and targets, but with a weapon doing a Line Pattern. Intuitively it seems the cover should apply for weapons such as a Railgun, but perhaps not for some other types of Line attacks.

Obviously, a GM can always make a ruling, but I would like to know what the RAW (or errata or the like) say about the interaction, or a confirmation that the interaction is not officially disambiguated/clarified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Only one Pattern treats Cover differently.

Line, Cone, and Burst patterns all originate from the attacker's position as normal, but:

> **BLAST X**: affects characters within a radius of **X spaces**, drawn from a point within RANGE and line of sight. Cover and line of sight for the attacks are calculated based on the center of the blast, rather than the position of the attacker.
>
> -- "Mech Combat", p.64, *LANCER Core Rulebook*

An arcing blast weapon can ignore the line-of-sight requirement for placing the blast center, but the blast itself still follows normal line-of-sight and cover rules: if you can draw a clean line between a cover-adjacent mech and the center of the blast, the covered mech is flanked by the blast and the cover penalty does not apply.